# API for Validating OAuth Access Token

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, rest, remote-access

Here is my usecase,

I have two apps, one written in rails and other is written in R.
App written on rails acts as landing page. From there we can go in to app written in R.

We are using Salesforce OAuth to get authenticated for rails app. And we want to use the same access token in R apps as well.

Accesss token fetched in rails app can be passed to R app along with instance URL. Now in R app how can we make sure the Access token is valid?
Is there any API which will check whether the accesstoken is valid or not?

If we have the API I can just make sure the access token is valid in R app.

Comment: You can just hit up the endpoint assuming it's valid and then handle the non-valid response (obtain new access token using the refresh token etc.)

Comment: Thats the approach I have to take, if we don't have any API to validate access token.

Comment: I don't think such an endpoint exists, but even if it does, why would you do an additional round-trip to the server?

Comment: My R app does not require to get any thing from salesforce. It just needs to be authenticated against salesforce. I such case, just verifying my accesstoken with API would be good. Else I would like to use some simple API's like get [userinfo] (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_getuserinfo.htm). Do we have eqivalent REST API?

Comment: If your app does not require to get anything from Salesforce, what's the reason for the token? Here is the REST API doc and how to retrieve standard object data - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_get_field_values.htm

Comment: Our rails app requires salesforce. We don't want all R app to be open and we don't want another authentication in R app. So we thought its better to pass the access token and just validate it in R app. I think I can make use of this api call. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_discoveryresource.htm. Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: @Bachovski Can you please update your answer based on these comments. It might be useful for other as well

Comment: Answer updated, if this answers you question please accept and close it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen such a thing, although even if it existed it would have been pointless to perform an additional round-trip to the server and introduce unnecessary delays when loading the app.

I would always go with the assumption that the token is still valid and hit my desired endpoint regardless. You should wrap this into a `try/catch` block and deal with the invalid token response accordingly.

**Update:**

As per your last comment, if your other app does not require to be connected to Salesforce, I suggest you to seek alternative validation rather than using the token. The token is only valid for a short period of time which will also invalidate the other app (unless that's your goal, then you could as I said reach out to any SF endpoint to validate the response).

Comment: I just want to have the token to be valid for short duration

Answer (score 0):

If simple validation is enough in your case, you can use this..

You can decode the access token and can compare the expiration time with current timestamp. I think it is a simple Base64 encryption. If you decrypt the access token you will get the expiration time. 
Then check,

```
if(exp > currentTime)
{
   return "valid";
}else{
   return "invalid";
}
```